# Data structure for building website downloader in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, depth-first-search

I need to build a simplified website downloader. It will basically look through the links in the website and recursively download the html files to the local directory. Which data structure is most suitable for this? I know that I have to implement some kind of depth first search algorithm, is there any data structure library in core Java suitable for my task and will decrease the amount of coding I do? (I'm very new to Java) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I need to build a simplified website downloader. It will basically look through the links in the website and recursively download the html files to the local directory.

There exists many command line tools and graphical interface tools for doing this, e.g. [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), but if you insist on doing this yourself then continue reading.

> Which data structure is most suitable for this? I know that I have to implement some kind of depth first search algorithm, is there any data structure library in core Java suitable for my task and will decrease the amount of coding I do? (I'm very new to Java) Thanks!

Data structure and algorithm are two different things. Which data structure and algorithm is best for your purpose depends on the scale of your data and other factors. If this is a small application for crawling a small number of links, you may want to use recursive method to download each page and parse the pages for links for next downloading.

For a large scale web crawler, you probably want to have a look at [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) and some distributed approaches for storing data and downloading them simultaneously.

Some tools which may be useful are:

1. Apache common IO, [FileUitls.copyURLToFile](https://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile%28java.net.URL,%20java.io.File%29) function
2. Apache common [http-client](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)
3. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for parsing HTML

Comment: Hi, thanks, It's a programming assignment so yeah, have to implement on my own. It's small scale, just about 10 links in a website, just need to recursively go through the links in the site. Is there any data structure you recommend me to use?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by data. is it a set of links or files or directory structure? array list should be sufficient for a small application to store links from parsing each file. other structures depend on your requirements

Comment: It is a set of links, but the problem is that I don't really know how to recursively go through the pages to retrieve those links. But I know that I have to use a depth first search algorithm.

Comment: you are not searching for something therefore you should not need a search algorithm. if you don't know how to implement a recursion, try this https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+implement+a+recursive+method+in+java

Comment: Just noticed that! I'm not really sure how to do the recursion. I already have a function now which retrieves all the links on a Single page. By the way, I have to retrieve links for up to 4 levels, Level 0 being the links on the home page. Maybe should I ask this as another question? Haha..

Comment: yes, but you should attempt to do it yourself first and ask when you have a problem. with no evidence of effort, it's hard to get any help on SO.

Comment: Haha.. Right, was trying to paste the code here, but didn't turn out well. Will paste my code in a new question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think following two method can help you.. 
what you have to do is, provide a String array of links and it will download all the pages in the root directory. 
Ok this code help you partially, if you just want to download page.

```
    public static void downloadPage(String[] pageLink) {
URL url;
InputStream is = null;
DataInputStream dis;
String line;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("");

try {
for (int i = 0; i < pageLink.length; i++) {
url = new URL(pageLink[i]);
is = url.openStream();
dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
builder.append(line + "\n");
}
savePage(i + ".html", builder.toString());
builder.setLength(0);
}
} catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
mue.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
ioe.printStackTrace();
} finally {
try {
is.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
}
}
}

public static void savePage(String fileName, String text) {
PrintStream out = null;
try {
out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
out.print(text);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
if (out != null)
out.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of the other suggestions, you may also want to look at [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [Java Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html), as you're probably going to want to thread the downloads to make it faster.